# javascript google maps v3.14 - how to hide poi now?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I don't know if it's google's recent changes in 3.14 or if I'm missing something but I need to get rid of local businesses / points of interest on my map. [What's going on here?](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/388/) I need to hide disneyland and other similar points of interest.

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 16,
  zoomControl:false,
  streetViewControl:false,
  panControl:false,
  mapTypeControl:false,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  styles: {
    featureType: "poi",
    //elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [{
      visibility: "off"
    }]
  }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById("map"),
  mapOptions
);
```

Comment: the current version is 3.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`styles` is expected to be an array, but you provide an object.

Fixed style:

```
styles: [{
    featureType: "poi",
    //elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [{
        visibility: "off"
    }]
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/389/